# How to write in symbols the sum defining the indefinite integral of function f, in case one has no explicit formula for f?

Tags: calculus, soft-question, indefinite-integrals

- If I am told that $f(x) = x$, I can write that :

the indefinite integral of $f$ is  $\frac{x^2}{2} + C.$

- There might be cases in which it would be convenient to say the same thing for some function $f$, without having any explicit formula for $f$. In such cases, how could the sum be written? Is there a symbol to denote the first term of the sum?

What I would like is to be able to complete this general statement for an unspecified function f

" indefinite integral of $f =$ ______ $(x) +C $".

Comment: Quite often, when in need for an antiderivative of $f$, people tend to name it $F$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the function $f$ is continuous you can write something as
$$
\int_a^x f(t)dt +C
$$

Comment: A question I am asking myself is : is there a general method to find the number a for which the  area function is identical to this primitive F(x)+C where C is null.  As an example: is there a method to determine for which number a  an area function of f(x)=x is  F(x)=x²/2 + 0 = x²/2.

Comment: An area is a number and it is defined only if the two limits of integration are given. Anyway it is better if you write a different question for this different problem.

Comment: Thanks for this answer that makes clearer to me the link between area function ( " accumulation function") and indefinite integral.

Comment: This is only guaranteed to work if $f$ is continuous on the interval in question.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg: Yes thank you! I edit :)

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is to say

> If $F(x)$ is a function such that $F'(x)=f(x)$, then $$\int f(x)\,dx=F(x)+c.$$